# Unloading of image when ListItem leaves screen

Tags: android, image, listview, picasso

I am using an adapter to populate a ListView. To supply the image I am using the picasso library to load it from a URL and place it in an ImageView. However, if I scroll down (once the image has loaded on each ListItem that is visible) and that ListItem goes off the screen, if I scroll back up the image is gone and I have to wait for it to load again.

How can I make it so that once the image is loaded it will stay loaded regardless of it going on or off the screen. Or at least if it unloads it would be good if it reloaded instantly because otherwise it looks bad when it takes seconds to reload.

Thank you

Comment: You can use any image cache library. Universal library is good one.
Find the library here https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader

Comment: @Sripathi what is wrong with Picasso? It is also an image cache library.

Comment: Sorry I din't noticed that.. You mean your listitem is recycled, so that there is a delay to load the Image right? Have you used Holder in your listadapter?

Comment: @Sripathi I'm not actually too sure what is happening. I am assuming it is being recycled. Yeah, there is a delay. The first time it loads having a delay is no issue - it is normal to take a while to download. However, if I pass it again I expect there to be no delay as it has been downloaded. I do not think so - what is a holder?

Comment: You can prevent the recycling of the rowView using holders. 
static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image;
  }

refer http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html for more info about Holder

Comment: Show code. Picasso has a memory cache which prevents what you describe so long as you are using it correctly.

Comment: @JakeWharton The line in my GetView function of the Adapter class is Picasso.with(getContext()).load(track.getCoverUrl()).placeholder(R.drawable.ic_record).into(coverArt);

Comment: It also happend with me,I have implement it in my Listview but, when i scroll it up and down images are gone and wait half second to visible..and it creates bad view...can you help? @JakeWharton

Comment: this also happened for me, same usage.
 Picasso.with(convertView.getContext()).load(cBanner.getBannerId()).into(banner);